# How to remove optional fields from registration form

Tags: user, registration

In Joomla registration form, how do I remove the optional fields?
[image]

The User-Plugin is disabled.

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't fields that exist in the core registration form. You might have enabled a user profile plugin with custom profile fields, or you have replaced the core registration form with another one - could be a 3rd party extension you are using.